# pipe ls and awk to rsync

Tags: awk, rsync, pipe

Trying to complete a script with the following steps:
(1) select 1gig of most recently changed files across a number of subdirectories (2) preferably uses `rsync` to copy the files to local directory -- *I prefer `rsync` than cp as I can use features from `rsync` to skip existing files etc.*

for step 1, the following works and it gives me the newest files limited to 1gig

```
ls -lstrkR /volume1/cctv/* | grep \.mp4$ | awk ' 
  (size += $1) > 1*1024*1024 {exit}
  #{print "size=" size "\t" $1 "\t" $6 "\t" $7 " " $8 " "$9 "\t" $10}
  {print $10}
'
```

The output from the above looks like this:
file1.mp4
file2.mp4
etc.

I do not have the absolute path of each file and the files above are from several subdirectories of /volume1/cctv (as you can see `ls -R`)

I need to either:
**(a)** take the output from the above and pipe to rsync, OR
**(b)** execute cp on the files (but then can I work from this list without the absolute paths?)

Comment: don't throw away information (i.e. the full path to the file) that you'll need to use later.  in other words, apart from it being a bad idea in general to parse `ls`, don't use `ls -R`.  use something like `find /volume1/cctv/* -type f -iname '*.mp4' -exec stat -c '%Y\t%s\t%n\n' {} + | awk '...'` instead.  read `man stat` for details on the `-c` format string.  and note that this will fail if any filenames have linefeeds in them.

Comment: the stat command outputs mod-time in seconds since epoch, file size in bytes, and filename for each matching fle.  separated by tab characters, not spaces.

Comment: thanks, but.. I am trying `find -type f -iname '*.mp4' -exec stat -c '%Y\t%s\t%n\n' {} +` to see what comes out from that first and I get an error  `find: -exec CMD must end by ';'` .. the problem with the above though is that I lose the sort which I get from `ls`. If I can get find to work, how would I sort by date then?

Comment: change `+` to `\;`.   what OS are you running and what version of find?  you don't need the sort, you can do that in awk, that's why the stat includes the file size as the second field.  or put something like `sort -n -k2,2` in the pipeline between find and awk.

Comment: if your find doesn't understand `-exec +` then your stat probably doesn't understand `-c`.  check the man page to see if there is an equivalent option for your version of stat.

Comment: it's after 4am here and i have to get some sleep. i'll look in on this Question tomorrow sometime.

Comment: `uname -a`
Linux SAM 3.10.35 #5644 SMP Wed Oct 28 12:37:28 CST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux synology_cedarview_412+
its my Synology DS412+ SAN.

`man stat` does not show `-c` . I only have -f -L -t

All I need is a list of top xGig of most recently modified files under a folder structure (including subdirectories). The sort order should be date and there could be 400MB files and 2MB files. They should all add to xGIG. It may be that the 100GIG come from total of say 100files or 1000files. Does this help? Thanks for your help - have a good evening downunder.

Comment: a "for f in $(....)" construct probably gets you less headache than find | xargs or find -exec. Getting the absolute path for a file can be achieved with readlink...

Comment: ah, so it's busybox or tinybox.  it's going to be hard to do anything complicated using minimalist tools - primitive stat and find and sort etc.  is perl installed?  even without any extra modules, you could use that instead of awk because it can make up for the shortcomings of busybox (e.g. it has good `stat()` and `sort()` functions built-in)

Comment: does the NAS have any option to install full versions of standard tools like find and stat and gawk?

Comment: I installed ipkg so I could look for that. I have installed perl but my perl knowledge is limited and was not able to get that to work. effectively in perl I'd need to traverse a tree, get contents of all files, sort by date first then compile a list of files up to xGig size

Comment: you could just pipe the output of find into perl and process it similarly to how you'd do it with awk (but also using perl's stat() function and maybe sort() function too - they're built-in to perl and don't require any extra lib modules)

Answer (score 2):

This `perl` script should do what you want:  Given a NUL-separated list of filenames (e.g. from `find -print0`), output a list of the most recently modified filenames, as long as the total size of those files doesn't exceed 1GB (default).  You can specify the number of gigs for the maximum size on the command line - this can be any valid number, integer or floating point.

The NUL separator means that this will work with any filenames, even if they contain spaces or newlines.

```perl
$ cat select-newest-one-gig.pl
#! /usr/bin/perl -0

use strict;

my $gigs = shift || 1;

my $maxsize = $gigs * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ;  # 1GB
my $total = 0;

# a hash to contain the list of input filenames and their modtimes
my %filemtimes=();

# hash to contain the list of input filenames and their sizes
my %filesizes=();

# a hash to contain a list of filenames to output.
# use a hash for this so we don't need to write a `uniq` function.
my %outfiles=();

while (<>) {
   chomp;

   # 7th field of stat() is size in bytes.
   # 9th field of stat() is modime in secs since epoch

   my ($size,$mtime) = (stat($_))[7,9];
   $filesizes{$_} = $size;
   $filemtimes{$_} = $mtime;
}

# iterate through the %filemtimes hash in order of reverse mtime
foreach (reverse sort { $filemtimes{$b} <=> $filemtimes{$a} } keys %filemtimes) {
   my $size = $filesizes{$_};

   # add it to our list of filenames to print if it won't exceed $maxsize
   if (($size + $total) <= $maxsize) {
       $total += $size;
       $outfiles{$_}++;
   }
}

# now iterate through the %filesizes hash in order of reverse size
# just in case we can sequeeze in a few more files.
foreach (reverse sort { $filesizes{$b} <=> $filesizes{$a} } keys %filesizes) {
   my $size = $filesizes{$_};
   if (($size + $total) < $maxsize) {
       $total += $size;
       $outfiles{$_}++;
   }
}

# now print our list of files.  choose one of the following, for
# newline separated filenames or NUL-separated.   
#print join("\n", sort keys %outfiles), "\n";
print join("\000", sort keys %outfiles), "\000";
```

Save that as `select-newest-one-gig.pl` and make it executable with `chmod +x`.

Run it like this (e.g. for a max total file size of 10GB):

```
find /volume1/cctv/ -type f -iname '*.mp4' -print0 | ./select-newest-one-gig.pl 10
```

This perl script could fairly easily be modified to take one or more filename extensions (e.g. `.mp4`) as args and then run find itself using the `system()` function call and iterate over that rather than `while (<>)`.  It's probably simpler to just pipe `find`'s output into it - why re-invent the wheel?

The following perl script will list (or delete if you uncomment the last line) files that exist in the rsync target directory that *weren't* listed on stdin.  It assumes NUL-separated input, so is safe even with filenames that contain newlines.

```perl
$ cat unlink-others.pl
#! /usr/bin/perl -0

use strict;

my @files=();

# first arg is target dir, with default
my $targetdir = shift || '/path/to/rsync/target/dir/';

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    s/^.*\///;  # strip path
    push @files, quotemeta($_)
}
my $regexp=join("|",@files);

opendir(my $dh, $targetdir) || die "can't opendir $targetdir: $!\n";
my @delete = grep { ! /^($regexp)$/o && -f "$targetdir/$_" } readdir($dh);
closedir $dh;

print join(", ",@delete),"\n";
# uncomment next line if you're sure it will only delete what you want
# unlink @delete
```

Use it like this:

```sh
find /volume1/cctv/ -type f -iname '*.mp4' -print0 | \
    ./select-newest-one-gig.pl 10 > /tmp/files.list

rsync --from0 --files-from /tmp/files.list ... /path/to/rsync/target/dir/

./unlink-others.pl /path/to/rsync/target/dir/ < /tmp/files.list
```

Comment: if your find doesn't support `-print0` then remove it from the find command-line and also remove the `-0` from the `#!` line of the perl script.  This will lose the ability to safely handle filenames that have newlines in them.

Comment: cas thank you for the above. Truth is I've been trying since last Saturday to piece together the above script into the overall solution to achieve the result I need and I keep running into issues. I can take the output of the above, create a text file. I can then push that text file to rsync --files-from=filelist.txt ... the problem now is to delete from the target directory the files which are NOT in the filelist.txt -- I am thinking to iterate the target directory and delete the file if it does not exist in the filelist.txt - are you able to help me with that please?

Comment: why not just use `rsync`'s `--delete` option?

Comment: I tried, its not working. here is what I have done `rsync --times --recursive --delete --progress --files-from=./out5.txt / /volume1/gDrive-CCTV/` it doesnt delete them. When I searched for --delete not working, there are a lot of hits saying that --delete doesn't work. arghh

Comment: full output: 

`admin@SAM:~>rsync --times --recursive --delete --progress --files-from=./out5.txt / /volume1/gDrive-CCTV/
sending incremental file list
rsync: link_stat "/volume1/s/1/20151118PM/Garage20151118-234246-1447890166.mp4" failed: No such file or directory (2)

sent 2628 bytes  received 24 bytes  5304.00 bytes/sec
total size is 6433064699  speedup is 2425740.84
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1240) [sender=3.0.9]
`

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /volume/cctv
echo 0 >/tmp/sztally &&
find .// -name '*.[mM][pP]4' -type f -exec sh -fc '
     _cp(){ shift; echo cp "$@$0"; :; }
     read sz </tmp/sztally; IFS=/ g=$((1024*1024)); unset _f
     for   f in   $(ls -dkst "$@")
     do    case   $f  in
           ("")   f=${2+./${_f%[!0-9. ]*}} _f=${_f##*[pP]4?}
                  [ 0 -ne "$((g>(sz+${_f%??})))" ] &&
                  set "$f$@" && sz=$((sz+${_f%??})) _f=;;
           (*)    [ -z ${_f:+:} ] && set "" ${_f+"$@"}
                  _f=${_f:+$_f/}$f
           esac||  ! _cp "$@" || exit 255
     done; _cp "$@"; echo "$sz" >/tmp/sztally
'   "/destination/path" {} +
```

That works for me. I tested it in my own media directory, and it consistently aggregated only the newest 1gb worth of .mp4 files into a `cp` operation. I think the `ls` option you were looking for was `-d`, which will retain full pathnames for all of `ls`'s arguments. Here `find` seeks out all of the .mp4 files it can put together, and `ls` sorts its selections by modification time. The shell splits `ls`'s output on pathname delimiters - the `/` -  and so there is no issue with special characters in filenames, because special characters are never considered at all.

Strictly speaking, the `-s` option for `ls` doesn't report a file's size, but rather it reports a file's *used space*. These two concepts can differ, but in the case of compressed video files the likelihood that they do is surpassing small. This doesn't actually do a copy as written - it only `echo`'s the `cp` operation. If you test it and find it viable, remove the `echo` from the `_cp()` function.

This depends on a POSIX `ls`, `find`, `cp`, and `sh`.

Comment: thanks, I haven't run it yet but I cannot see an `rm` above. Remember I want to delete from the target directory files which are NOT in the most recent 1gb. So, step (1): select most recent 1gb and copy to target, step (2): delete from target. I prefer not to over-write existing files in target because the target-dir is synced with googledrive. I don't want to re-upload every day 1gig of data if only say 200MB has changed (the actual data limit I want to stay in is 100gig not 1gig). That is why I wanted to use `rsync` but I dont mind as long as `cp` ignores existing. Does this make sense?

Comment: @csolad - ok, so use `rsync` rather than `cp`. or `pax`. or `ln`. feel free to adapt it in any way you might require. as i said, as written it only echoes a filelist to the screen.