# ls without --time-style support

Tags: ls, busybox

I need the same output in `FMTIME` as in the following command:

```
FMTIME=`ls -l --time-style=+%s $FILE | cut -f6 -d' '`
```

but my Linux (running busybox) does not support `ls --time-style`. I am running ::

```
Linux SAM 3.10.35 #5644 SMP Wed Oct 28 12:37:28 CST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux synology_cedarview_412+
```

I have `stat` available and `awk` and `cut` .

Comment: can you provide output of stat `/etc/hosts` (by editing the question) ? as well as OS, so we can edit tags for this question.

Comment: What is the output of `stat --help` ? That will tell us the version.

Comment: @Archemar I don't think `/etc/hosts` is relevant.

Comment: @Mikel I was just expecting a sample output of SP's version of stat, to see how it can be combined with awk.

Comment: As discussed in your last question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242841/pipe-ls-and-awk-to-rsync , `busybox` has only basic versions of `ls`, `stat`, `find`, and many other tools.  You can use `perl`, which you have already installed, to work around many of these deficiencies.  so, learn perl.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
 stat -c %Y
```

- you might want to double check with `%X` and `%Z` as well.
- see stat(1) (e.g. `man stat`)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes right ! this is a typo, I copied it manually.

Comment: folks I am quite a novice. can you give me the full command, if I do FMTIME=`stat -c %Y` it does not work. My stat only allows -f or -L or -t . Should I do stat $FILE ? This will end up with 8-9 lines of text in FMTIME. I need FMTIME to have exactly the same output as in the original command. thanks

Comment: @csolad No, do `stat -c %Y "$FILE"`.

Comment: Mikel as I said in my comment above, my stat only allows -f or -L or -T. so your reply doesn't help in any way unfortunately.